# Pip is closing after submitting a searchable query

Tags: android, android-search, android-picture-in-picture

I have an edge case when pip is enabled and the user wants to search something, the pip will get dismissed(when the user submit a query which has more than one item).
The search component is based on `<searchable>` and we used `SearchViewListener`
to get feedback from the search view component.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
        saveSearchSelection(query);
        fetchSearchResults(query, FULL_RESULTS_LIMIT);
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I change the return value to true, the pip is not being dismissed but I get another issue that when you click on back after you clicked on item you will return to the main activity instead of the previous list which is a regression.
I was wondering if there is a different solution which won't involve to rewrite the whole search list results just to support pip

Thanks

**update**

I had today more time to play with the code and I think I found the reason why the pip is closing. We are enabling voice search from

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
//Set up SearchableInfo (need this for voice search)
      SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), UnifiedSearchResultsActivity.class)));
}
```

when I remove those two lines the pip is not closing and continuing playing without any issues. I was wondering if someone had this issue or knows how to fix it. We are also targeting API level 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to fix this issue using the following code

```
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```